# Using a number that is smaller

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

```
<v-text-field
  type="number"   
  min="1"
  v-model.number="number"
></v-text-field>
```

this `text-field` accepts writing numbers smaller than `min="1"`.

How to prevent users from inputting numbers smaller then '1' ? It is possible in vuetify ?

Answer (score 0):

no you need conditional programming like so

```
if(num < 1){
//code
}
```